# Generate a Javascript function call graph with doxygen and graphviz across multiple files

Tags: javascript, doxygen, graphviz

I am currently using Doxygen and Graphviz to generate documentation for a website. The website has many Javascript files, with function calls that go across to multiple files. The call graphs currently generated are bounded inside each individual file.

Is there any way to generate a call graph of a function that spans multiple files? I was thinking about using `cat` to concatenate all the files I want the call graph span, and then passing that as an argument into Graphviz or Doxygen generator, but I am unable to find a way to generate a call graph by command line.

### Example

If I have the following two files *main.js* and *sub.js*:

#### main.js

```
mainFunc(){
    subFunc();
}
```

#### sub.js

```
subFunc(){
    sayHi("hello");
}
sayHi(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

I want to be able to generate a call graph that looks like this:

[mainFunc] -> [subFunc] -> [sayHi]

Even if it's not automated. A command that looks like this would be fine:

`cat main.js sub.js | doxygen -makecall "mainFunc" -o myGraph.svg`

Comment: In the past there was a script js2doxy.pl (see http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/helpers.html). I found one at https://github.com/schteppe/ammo.js-demos/tree/master/doc and https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-oldtestingconfigs/tree/master/doc, but I have no idea about its quality.